# Detecting a sub-string

Tags: sql, string, delphi, filtering

I have a lot of data that I need to sort through and one of the fields contains both the make/model of the vehicle as well as the reg, sometimes separated by a dash (-) sometimes however it is not. Here is an example of such a string:

> VehicleModel - TU69YUP
>
> VehicleModel - TU69 YUP
>
> VehicleModel TU69YUP
>
> VehicleModel TU69 YUP

There are also some other variations but they are the main ones I have encountered. Is there a way that I can reliably go through all of the data and separate the vehicle reg from the model?

The data is currently contained within a Paradox database which I have no problem going through. I do not have a list of all of the vehicle models and names that are contained within the database, likewise, I also do not have a list of the licence plates.

The project is written in Delphi/SQL so I would prefer to stick with either one of these if at all possible.

Comment: To do that you need a distinct delimiter which seperates the strings. This is only the case if the data itself does not contain that delimiter / if it does not contain the delimiter more than once if it is unique on all strings. In example 4 you have two spaces. That means you can't surely tell wether 'TU69' belongs to the vehicle model oder the license number (unless there are restrictions - e.g. the license number had to be 7 chars)

Comment: Do the `VehicleModel` values ever contain spaces? If not, this can be pretty easy, but if you have things like `Ford Mustang`, not so much. Can the `VehicleModel` ever contain numbers? Is the `reg` always two letters followed by numbers? Can you edit to provide more information about the data you're working with? (Maybe using a few more samples of the `VehicleModel` instead of just repeating that word in each sample.)

Comment: I'm not sure space in the `vehiclemodel` will be a problem if the `reg` values are sufficiently uniform - in that case, you could parse tokens from right to left.  So, does the `reg` have a standard length (ignoring whitespace)?  Also, is `-` (dash) the only delimiter that is used?  If yes to both of these, it'll be easy.

Comment: the VRM given is a current UK number plate and that is AANNAAA and has been since 2001, but in the UK we have a number of formats and alot of cherished transerfers (personal plates/NI plate) in current use.  Also there are alot of pre 2001 plates still in used so the possible number of VRM formats is unfortuantly quite wide,  However nearly all of the plates will be 5 chars or more in lentgh, so you can use that to get most of the plates from the end of the string, ie trace back to first space, if less that 5 char (or 4 probably) continue to next space ( or non alpahnum char)

Comment: +1. Why are people downvoting this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Trouble ahead

If that field was originally entered by a user in the form that you're now seeing, then we can assume there was no validation, the original program would simply store whatever the user entered. If that's the case, you can't get 100% accuracy: human beings will always make mistakes, intentionally or unintentionally. Expect this kinds of human errors:

- Missing fields (ie: registration only, no vehicle information - or the other way around)
- Meaningless duplication of words (example: "Ford Ford K - TU 69 YUP")
- Missing letters, duplicated letters, extra garbage letters. Example: "For K - T69YUP"
- Wrong order of fields
- Other small errors you can't even dream of.
- Plain garbage that not even a human would make sense of.

You might have guessed I'm a bit pessimistic when dealing with human-entered data straight into text fields. I had the distinct misfortune to deal with a database where all data was text and there was no validation: Can you guess the kind of nonsense people typed in unvalidated date fields that allowed free user input?

#### The plan

Things aren't as dark as they seem, you can probably "fix" lots of things. The trick here is making sure you only fix data that's unambiguous and let a human sift through the rest of the stuff. The easiest way to do that is to do something like this:

- Look at the data you have and wasn't automatically fixed yet. Figure out a rule that unambiguously applies to lots of records.
- Apply the unambiguous rule.
- Repeat until only a few records are left. Those should be fixed by hand, because they resisted all automatic methods that were applied.

#### The implementation

I strongly recommend using regular expressions for all the tests, because you'll surely end up implementing lots of different tests, and regular expressions can easily "express" the slight variations in search text. For example the following reg-ex can parse all 4 of your examples and give the correct result:

```
(.*?)(\ {1,3}-\ {1,3})?(\b[A-Z]{2}\ {0,2}[0-9]{2}\ {0,3}[A-Z]{3}\b)
```

If you've never worked with regular expressions before, that single expressions looks unintelligible, but it's in fact very simple. This is not a reg-ex question so I'm not going into any details. I'd rather explain how I've come up with the idea.

First of all, if the text includes vehicle registration numbers, those numbers will be in a very strict format: they'd be easy to match. Given your example I assume all registration numbers are of the form:

```
LLNNLLL
```

where "L" is a letter and "N" is a number. My regex is rigid in it's interpretation of it: it wants exactly two uppercase letters, followed by a small number of spaces (or no space), followed by exactly two digits, followed by a small number of spaces (or no space), finally followed by exactly 3 uppercase letters. The part of the regex that deals with that is:

```
[A-Z]{2}\ {0,2}[0-9]{2}\ {0,3}[A-Z]{3}
```

The rest of the regex makes sure the registration number isn't found embedded into other words, deals with grouping text into capture groups and creates an "lazy capture group" for the VehicleModel.

If I were to implement this myself, I'd probably write a "master" function and a number of simpler "case" functions, each function dealing with one kind of variation in user input. Example:

```
// This function does a validation of the extracted data. For example it validates the
// Registration number, using other, more precise criteria. The parameters are VAR so the
// function may normalize the results.
function ResultsAreValid(var Make, Registration:string): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True; // Only you know what your data looks like and how it can be validated.
end;

// This is a case function that deals with a very rigid interpretation of user data
function VeryStrictInterpretation(const Text:string; out Make, Registration: string): Boolean;
var TestMake, TestReg: string;
    // regex engine ...
begin
  Result := False;
  if (your condition) then
    if ResultsAreValid(TestMake, TestReg) then
    begin
      Make := TestMake;
      Registration := TestReg;
      Result := True;
    end;    
end;

// Master function calling many different implementations that each deal with all sorts
// of variations of input. The most strict function should be first:
function MasterTest(const Text:string; out Make, Registration: string): Boolean;
begin
  Result := VeryStrictInterpretation(Text, Make, Registration);
  if not Result then Result := SomeOtherImplementation(Text, Make, Registration);      
  if not Result then Result := ThirdInterpretation(Text, Make, Registration);      
end;
```

The idea here is to try to make multiple SIMPLE procedures, that each understands one kind of input in an unambiguous way; And make sure each step doesn't return false positives! And finally don't forget, a human should deal with the last few cases, so don't aim for a fix-it-all solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well assuming that they are of the same format. Word[space]Word

Then you can iterate through them all, and if you encounter a whitespace without a dash, insert a dash. Then split as normal.

Comment: This doesn't reliably work unless no more than one entity is not of fixed length. In his fourth example you would end up with three entities: VehicleModel - TU69 - YUP

Comment: Not if it is just the first instance

Comment: easier to replace - with a space

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code example.
It will check for the `-` and also remove possible spaces in the license number.

**Note :** (as commented by Ken White), if the vehicle contains a space, this will have to be handled as well.

```
type
  EMySplitError = class(Exception);

procedure SplitVehicleAndLicense( s : String; var vehicle,license : String);
var
  p : Integer;
begin
  vehicle := '';
  license := '';
  p := Pos('-',s);
  if (p = 0) then
  begin // No split delimiter
    p := Pos(' ',s);
    if (p > 0) then
    begin
      vehicle := Trim(Copy(s,1,p-1));
      license := Trim(Copy(s,p+1,Length(s)));
    end
    else
      Raise EMySplitError.CreateFmt('Not a valid vehicle/license name:%s',[s]);
  end
  else
  begin
    vehicle := Trim(Copy( s,1,p-1));
    license := Trim(Copy( s,p+1,Length(s)));
  end;

  // Trim spaces in license
  repeat
    p := Pos(' ',license);
    if (p <> 0) then Delete(license,p,1);
  until (p = 0);
end;
```